# How to define a custom directory so that I can cd directory in Matlab

Tags: matlab, directory, cd

Suppose I have a directory

```
cur = 'C:\Windows\debug';
```

Then I can run `cd(cur)` now. But I'm not used to using the function format. I hope I can use `cd cur` to change the current folder directly. Is this possible in MATLAB?

Edit: Because I'm getting the following error:

```
>> cur = 'C:\Windows\debug';
>> cd cur
Error using cd
Cannot CD to cur (Name is nonexistant or not a directory).
```

Comment: To `cd` to a directory contained in a variable, as you are trying, you must use the functional form.  In your example MATLAB is looking for a directory called `cur`.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Of course I know,But I I'm want to do this still.Is there any workaround?

Comment: To quote the documentation for `Command vs. Function Syntax`: `When a function input is a variable, you must use function syntax to pass the value to the function. Command syntax always passes inputs as literal text and cannot pass variable values`.  I don't believe there's a workaround.

Comment: @PhilGoddard,Wolfie Thanks.Just because I'm a *Linux* user,it hard to used to use cd(dir) to change the directory.I thinks must exist some method can make the variable release its value in the command line directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [documentation for command syntax](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html#f76-1098266), and a documentation article with more examples on [command vs function syntax](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html).

From the docs,

> When calling a function using command syntax, MATLAB passes the arguments as character vectors.

So no, you cannot pass a variable name like `cur`, because `cur` will get treated as a character vector and you will be doing the same as `cd('cur')`.

You can do either

```
cd(cur)
% or
cd 'C:\Windows\debug'
% or (as long as no whitespace in directory path)
cd C:\Windows\debug
```

If you don't like learning the syntax, the workaround is to choose another language... Using brackets is standard practise in MATLAB, since you also cannot get output values from a function when using command syntax.

Also from the [scripts and functions documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts-and-functions.html) you can see the message

> **Caution:** While the unquoted command syntax is convenient, in some cases it can be used incorrectly without causing MATLAB to generate an error.

So this method is discouraged when using MATLAB.

Comment: I'm highly doubt [that command](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nq2D.png) can work still.And the `cd(cur)` work normally in here.

Comment: Sorry,I have known the sytax actually,I just hard to used to use cd like that style.

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to get used to it, there isn't a workaround. I hope this answer provided useful information, if so consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks anyway,if there are no solution still after 36h,I will accept it.